# Use object storage for blobs

Tags: java, xodus

We use Entity *blobs* to store documents, images, small audio and videos in our platform.

And I understand this is quite expensive in terms of cloud storage not to mention the limits of block storage (the max I know is 10TB) this can easily get consume storing audio and video files (even small ones)

What is the blob solution that an Enitty blob can be mapped to an *object storage* that can scale better in capacity without losing the ability for the blob to be linked to the `Entity`, i.e. `Entity.geBlobNames` can on on disk while the actual binary would be on an object storage, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like a feature request, could you please file it? Thanks.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=XD

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-818